# Can a backbone model be used with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

Here is sample of one backbone post model:

```
var Post = Backbone.AssociatedModel.extend({
    urlRoot: ApiService.resolveRESTUrl('posts'),
    defaults: {
        age : 0,
        fname : "",
        lname : "",
        manager : null
    },
    relations:[
        {
            type:Backbone.One,
            key:'User',
            relatedModel: function(){ return $injector.get('UserModel') },
            collectionType: function(){return $injector.get('UserModel').Collection; }
        },
        {
            type:Backbone.Many,
            key:'Last3Comments',
            relatedModel:function(){ return $injector.get('CommentModel')  },
            collectionType:function(){ return $injector.get('CommentModel').Collection },
        }
    ],
    getTimeAgo:function() {},
    getPicture:function(size){
        return this.get('picture_url') ?
            ApiService.getImageResizeUrl(this.get('picture_url'),'w'+size+'xh'+size) :
            null;
    },
});
```

when posts are loading and if any lib using angular watcher in post array (data binded with "=")
then i am getting following error

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

and also

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at Array.toString (native)

I am watching posts like this:

```
$scope.posts=[];
$scope.$watch('posts', function(model) {
    console.log($scope.posts, model);
},true);
$scope.loadPosts=function(){
    if($scope.loading || $scope.disabled) return;

    $scope.loading=true;

    ApiService.request("posts/home",{page:$scope.page,limit:10}).success(function(data){
        $scope.loading=false;
        $scope.page++;
        if(data.error){
            alert('Error');
        } else {
            if(data.data.posts.length==0)
                $scope.disabled=true;
            $.each(data.data.posts,function(i,e){
               var post=new PostModel(e);

                $scope.posts.push(post);
            });
        }
    }).error(function(){
        alert('Error');
        $scope.loading=false;
    });
};
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: if i do posts=[newaarrayofmodels] then it works else no, and i've tried both objectEquality=true and false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, using angular's watchCollection instead of just watch because watchCollection is used to watch array.